# Array size in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Using Visual Studio 2012, if I type the following:

```
char bytes[ 2*1024*1024*1024 ];
```

I get the error: "matrix size must be greater than zero". The same occurs if I declare the size dynamically, i.e.:

```
char* bytes = new char[ 2*1024*1024*1024 ];
```

If I remove the first "2", everything is fine. It seems as there's a hard limit on the amount of memory I can request either from the stack or the heap, being this limit 1 GB. However, given that size_t is 4 bytes in the worst case (it could be 8 bytes almost for sure), there is not any problem in the index not being able to address all the space of the array. Is the problem that the limit imposed to the stack and the heap is 1MB by default? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90ybzkh(v=vs.110).aspx). If this is the case, then why can I allocate 1 GB?

Comment: You're overflowing the size of an `int` in the size expression.

Comment: VC++ doesn't report 'Matrix size must be...'. It reports, 'Negative subscript' or 'the size of array must be greater than zero'

Comment: @Ajay Well, you may be right. I'm using Visual Studio in Spanish and I just made a literal translation of the compiler message. The translation in Visual Studio may be inaccurate though. Sorry if that creates confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take care not to overflow a 32 bit int expression - `2*1024*1024*1024` is `2^31`, which is 1 larger than `INT_MAX`. Try:

```
char bytes[ 2ULL*1024*1024*1024 ];
```

Note that the compile error has nothing to do with stack or heap size. Whether you can actually allocate this amount of memory is a separate problem.

Comment: 1. "this is" or "this has"? 2. Worth mentioning that it cannot be executed on a 32-bit system (requires 64-bit address space).

Comment: @barakmanos: is that a Windows-specific limitation ? Most sensible 32 bit environments allow allocations > 2 GB.

Comment: Well I meant `>4GB`... In this case, `2GB` is indeed supported on 32-bit systems, my mistake (your `ULL` got me thinking that it was larger than 4GB, so I didn't bother to do the math).

Comment: But I think that it still has a lot to do with stack/heap size. Perhaps you meant that the standard doesn't say anything about where the array is allocated. So in theory this statement is correct. But in practice, the array will be allocated in the stack, in the data-section or in the heap. If there is not "enough room" there, then the program will not execute correctly (or will not execute at all).

Comment: @barakmanos: the question is about the compiler error "matrix size must be greater than zero" - the error itself has nothing to do with stack or heap size - whether you can actually allocate this amount of memory or not is a secondary problem.

Comment: I thought that the type of the size of an array was size_t, and I assumed that the expression 2*1024*1024*1024 would be considered as such, and not as a 32 bit int expression. With your suggestion, the compiler error has disappeared though.

Comment: You're right that it is a `size_t`, but there is no implicit cast within the expression, so it's as if you wrote e.g. `size_t size = 2*1024*1024*1024;`, i.e. the damage has already been done before the value of the expression is converted to `size_t`.